# What's the meaning of "I Will Not Pass This Way Again"

Tags: sentence-meaning, interpretation

In [The Sense of Style](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0143127799), Steven Pinker quoted this church bulletin

> Miss Charlene Mason sang, "I Will Not Pass This Way Again," giving obvious pleasure to the congregation.

The church bulletin blooper is supposed to be funny because it's ambiguous — it's not clear whether the singing (intended) or the not-passing-this-way-again (unintended) caused the pleasure.

I didn't get it though. How is the unintended sense funny?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intended meaning is that the congregation enjoyed the singing, but the literal meaning of the song is "I won't come here again". Suppose the congregation were pleased by that fact and not by the singing.

That is, the unintended meaning is "Her singing was so bad that the congregation were pleased that she won't come back and sing again."
It's funny because of the unintended schadenfreude, but it's not *very* funny.

Comment: I think I first saw that quote in a _Reader's Digest_ that my parents bought around 1962. More since, variations including e.g. Mary Smith, aged 8, at a school concert.

Comment: Sometimes it's a violin.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Thanks a lot :)